# What is the method on an onOptionsItemSelected menu in WebView for "forward" and "back" in Android?

Tags: android, methods, menu, back, forward

I am trying to get my webView to move back and forward by calling up the menu. Thus far I have the menu working fine and opening, and the refresh button will refresh the browser. However, I cannot find documentation anywhere about the methods for forward of back. If the default internet browser has them by just pressing the menu key there must be out there. I just can't find them/don't know how to implement them. Any help would be beneficial, thank you.

Here is what I am trying to do:

WebView.Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.back_button:

        "???"

    case R.id.forward_button:

        "???"

    case R.id.refresh_button:
            refreshBrowser();
            return true;
          } 
    return false;
   }
```

The part that I'm missing is marked by the three question marks "???". Let me know if you need more information to get some help, and thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use webView.canGoBack and webView.canGoForward to check if there is history data to go back / forward and then load that url.

Comment: Excellent! These methods worked great, thank you so much for your help. When I first tried implementing this solution I was noticing that using just webView.canGoBack was not working. However, I figured out that I had set my "browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);" after the onCreate() method, so all I had to do after was to add the browser.canGoBack(); Thank you for your time in answering my question, now I have great back/forward/refresh buttons.